# Load multiple images in Air not working properly?

Tags: apache-flex, image, actionscript, air, load

So I made a drag and drop app where I can drop in an image, it get's resized and saved automatically on the desktop.

But now I want to do the same when there are multiple images dragged in.
This is where I'm stuck...

```
private function onDrop(e:NativeDragEvent):void
{
    trace("Dropped!");
    var dropfiles:Array = e.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) as Array;
    for each (var file:File in dropfiles){

        var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
        ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

        switch (file.extension.toLowerCase()){
            case "png" :
                ldr.load(new URLRequest(file.url));
                trace('png');                     
                break;
            case "jpg" :
                ldr.load(new URLRequest(file.url));
                trace('jpg');
                break;
            case "jpeg" :
                ldr.load(new URLRequest(file.url));
                trace('jpeg');
                break;
            case "gif" :
                ldr.load(new URLRequest(file.url));
                break;
            default:
                Alert.show("Kies een geldige afbeelding!");
        }
    }
}

private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    var ldr:Loader = Loader(event.target.loader);
    var b:Bitmap = Bitmap(ldr.content);
    var encoder:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
    var bytes:ByteArray = encoder.encode(resizeimage(b.bitmapData, 600, 600));

    //new FileReference().save(bytes, "abc.png");
}
```

The problem is that I want the completeHandler() to run after every ldr.load() but in my code it only runs once right after the for each loop.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you the Loaders are only referenced as local variables. After the function `onDrop` ends, they're probably getting garbage collected. Once that happens, they won't be around to call your event handler. You need to save them somewhere to keep them memory.

I'd save them in an Array. Make a private variable on your class, like this:

```
private var _loaders:Array = [];
```

Then, when you create a Loader, save it:

```
var ldr:Loader = new Loader()
_loaders.push(ldr);
```

In your completeHandler, or whereever you're done with the Loader, be sure to remove it from the Array:

```
var index:int = _loaders.indexOf(ldr);
_loaders.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: By the way, it's a common misconception that adding an event listener to a dispatcher creates a reference to the dispatcher. It's the other way around, though. The dispatcher holds a reference to the listener, and there is no extra reference to the dispatcher.